# How to Apply sensitivity label to files stored in SharePoint Online or OneDrive using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, onedrive, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection

The task is to write a code that applies a sensitivity label to a document in a SharePoint Online document library without downloading the file.
We have already tried applying sensitivity label to offline documents using "Set-AIPFileLabel" command.
Is there any way we can apply sensitivity label to directly files stored in SharePoint Online sites using PowerShell commands or REST APIs?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, I'm afraid there is no such PowerShell commnad or API can apply sensitivity label too specific files in a SharePoint Online library.

Answer (score 0):

There's now an API in beta on Microsoft Graph which will allow you to set a sensitivity label on a file by calling into i.e.

```
POST /sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{item-path}/assignSensitivityLabel
```

More information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-assignsensitivitylabel?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Note that this is a metered API though, so there will be a charge for every 10,000 calls you make to this API.

Comment: Nice! This beats downloading every file over OneDrive to apply a label locally.